# How to implement if-else branch in a abstract syntax tree using C++

Tags: c++, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a mini AST structure in which each node may have a left and a right child, for example:

```
class AstNode;
typedef std::shared_ptr<AstNode> AstNodePtr;

class AstNode
{
public:
    AstNode()
        : m_children(2)
    {
    }

    virtual ~AstNode()
    {
    }

    virtual void accept(AstNodeVisitor& visitor) = 0;

    void addLeft(const AstNodePtr& child);
    void addRight(const AstNodePtr& child);
    const AstNodePtr left() const;
    const AstNodePtr right() const;

private:
    std::vector<AstNodePtr> m_children;
};
```

It works great for the operations I need so far, but when it comes to a branch statement, I don't know how to implement it with this binary tree structure. According to wiki, a branch statement will have 3 leaves:

[image]

I can get away with it for now because most of my if statement has no else, so the condition will be the left child, and if-body will be the right child. But it's not going to work with a else-body. I can potentially embed condition in the branch node itself, which means do a pre-order traversal on branch node, but it feels uncomfortable because no other type of nodes involve potential subtree traversal when evaluating itself.

Maybe the AST should not be a binary tree, rather each node can have any number of children, but that will(I think) make the implementation a bit awkward. Any suggestions please?

Comment: You are right, the AST should not be a binary tree.

Comment: Can you please share your code, I am also trying to solve the same problem. I am not getting how to implement code for if-else block

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the nature, ASTs should be implemented in multi-child trees to support if-condition-then expressions. But a workaround could be having 2 types for IF;

- if-block(left:condition, right:if-body)
- if-body(left:any, right: any)

left child of the if-body is used if condition of the parent is true, right child is used otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

You could define an abstract AST node which doesn't hold any children. Then for each number of child nodes ("arity"), define a different subclass:

- a **unary** AST node for things like `return` or for unary operators such as negation
- a **binary** AST node for binary operations
- a **ternary** AST node for `if-then-else` constructs as well as for the ternary operator `?!`
- maybe a dynamic **n-ary** AST node for the set of cases in a `switch-case` construct, if you want to support them. Your `statement-sequence` perfectly fits into this node type, too. If you don't implement this node type, you could put statement sequences in a binary tree structure, but that sounds like a dirty hack.
- maybe a **four-ary** (is this the name?) AST node for `for` loops. They have an initial, a conditional and an incremental statement plus a body.

Note that implementing everything with dynamically sized children lists is a bad idea in my opinion, since it doesn't make sense to have a node of type `operator =` with only one child, as an example.

Then, inherit the concrete node types from the node class corresponding to the arity.

```
class ASTNode {
public:
    virtual ASTNode() {}
    virtual void accept(AstNodeVisitor& visitor) = 0;
};

// ----

class ASTNodeUnary : public ASTNode {
protected:
    AstNodePtr c1;
};

class ASTNodeBinary : public ASTNode {
protected:
    AstNodePtr c1, c2;
};

class ASTNodeTernary : public ASTNode {
protected:
    AstNodePtr c1, c2, c3;
};

class ASTNodeDynamic : public ASTNode {
protected:
    std::vector<AstNodePtr> children;
};

// ----

class ASTNodeBranch : public ASTNodeTernary {
    ...
};
```

and so on

Comment: Four-nary is Quaternary.